# Cannot send email in html format from webserver

Tags: email, smtp

Hi i am working on an email system which is used to send email when user is registered on the site. The email when sent in plain text format is delivered correctly but it fails to get delivered even when everything goes ok with the script when sent in html format. It doesn't even work when I use aol or gmail smtp server for sending it. Does my webserver bans email from sending in html format or there's any other problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not so much the server, but probably the email client.
Depending on the sort of formatting you used in the html, it's far more likely for the email to be rejected by either the email reader, or some spam filter along the way.

First try sending the email including both parts - the text part and the html part, but keep the formatting in the html part to a bare minimum. (ie start with no formatting.) Then slowly increase the formatting to see when it stops. Links for example should be completely "straight" - show the user everything in the link - the text should match the href. Buttons are not allowed.

No mater what you do, html emails will always have a higher filter rate than text ones, so carefully consider the use of html in the first place. It doesn't matter how pretty the email is if it doesn't get delivered.

Comment: I tried everything. But emails are not delivered. There is no error message when email is sent. I want to know whether my webserver bans me from sending emails in html format. How can I enable it for my site?

Comment: Of course it's possible that the email component you are using on your web site does not allow for html emails to be sent - but you've given no information on the programming side, so I don't think anyone can answer your question from a programming point of view. I'm assuming you can monitor your email server to see (in the logs) if your email has arrived at the server.